# Implementing $AB\bar{C}D+A\bar{D}+\bar{A}D$ using only AND & XOR gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

**Question:**

> Implement $F(A,B,C,D)=AB\bar{C}D+A\bar{D}+\bar{A}D$ using only AND & XOR gates

---

**My try:**

I know that $A\bar{D}+\bar{A}D$ functions like a XOR gate which takes $A$ and $D$ as input. But then I don't know what to do which the part $+AB\bar{C}D$. I mean, with this method, I'm stuck on designing the OR gate.
I also tried using the Karnaugh map to simplify the equation but the result didn't help me either.
It seems that there's no way to get rid of the OR gate...

---

Any idea on this implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you allowed to use $0$ or $1$?

Comment: @Bram28 the question doesn't mention it... Is it possible not to use $0$ or $1$ ?

Comment: If you have a $1$ then you can do any functin, since $\{ \land, \oplus, 1 \}$ is expressively complete ... but $\{ \land , \oplus \}$ is not expressively complete ... which does not mean that this specific function cannot be captured ... but it is possible that it can't ... let me try ...

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks for taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just $XOR$ and $AND$ gates it cannot be done:  By induction you can prove that any function composed of $XOR$'s and $AND$'s will be true in at most half of the cases, and the function you are supposed to capture is true in $9$ out of $16$ cases.

If you can use a $1$ as an input as well, then you can do it, since to capture $P'$ you can use $P \ XOR \ 1$, and with the conjunction and the negation you have an expressively complete system.

For your particular function:

$$ABC'D + AD' + A'D =$$

$$ABC'D+ (A \ XOR \ D)=$$

$$((ABC'D)'(A \ XOR \ D)')'=$$

$$(((AB(C \ XOR \ 1)D) \ XOR \ 1)((A \ XOR \ D) \ XOR \ 1)) \ XOR \ 1$$